# Folders when connecting to live sources in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, google-cloud-dataflow, powerbi-datasource

I was wondering if you could help

I am connecting to a life to server or datasets for my PowerBI dashboard

I was just wondering, is it possible at all to create folders for the tables in the datasets?

To have all tables and DAX Measures related to training in "Training" folder, all people in "People" folder etc

I know this is definitely an option when copying the information into PowerBI, but what about when connecting live?

Thank you in advance

N/A

Not sure how to even start

Comment: You can create measure folders within a table, and you can create query folders in PowerQuery, but I don't believe you can currently organize tables into folders. That indeed would be a very handy feature.

Comment: Thanks Luke

I don't even get a chance to utilize PowerQuery in this instance with me connecting to server or datasets live, but thank you for clarifying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this answer as a wiki for better visibility for other users. As @Luke_0 suggests you can create folders within PowerQuery, but organising tables into folders is not yet feature:

> You can create measure folders within a table, and you can create query folders in PowerQuery, but I don't believe you can currently organize tables into folders. That indeed would be a very handy feature.

Possible Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-measures